# How to generate PUT presigned URL for an object when bucket has object lock enabled using AWS SDK 2 for java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have to generate presigned url to upload object on the bucket using AWS SDK 2. Up-until I am doing this with bucket with object lock disabled it is working fine but when I am doing it with bucket with object lock enabled it is throwing error that I should send MD5 encryption. My question here is at the time of creation when I don't know about the file then how am I supposed to generate its md5 encryption and create the presigned url with it. Anybody please help me in understanding this and how this can be implemented.

I used the simple code that is given on official website to generate the presigned url nothing new.

Comment: What do you mean by you dont know about the file_  You are doing a PUT, so you should have the file.

Comment: In our design the file is given to the presigned url through different service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For **SDK Version 2**, there is an open feature request: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2155

For **SDK Version 1**, you could use `Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(file)` to determine the MD5 of the file.   See Closed Bug: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2634

MD5Utils also exists in Version 2

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/utils/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/utils/Md5Utils.java

---

Note

> If you configure a default retention period on a bucket, requests to
> upload objects in such a bucket must include the Content-MD5 header.
> For more information, see Put Object in the Amazon Simple Storage
> Service API Reference.

It seems that the `Content-MD5` header restriction is applied only if you have a (**Retention Period set**).

So if you do have a Retention Period, then yes you must provide `Content-MD5` Header.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock-overview.html

---

Note

```
To successfully complete the PutObject request, you must have the s3:PutObject in your IAM permissions.

To successfully change the objects acl of your PutObject request, you must have the s3:PutObjectAcl in your IAM permissions.

To successfully set the tag-set with your PutObject request, you must have the s3:PutObjectTagging in your IAM permissions.
```

**The Content-MD5 header is required for any request to upload an object with a retention period configured using Amazon S3 Object Lock. For more information about Amazon S3 Object Lock, see Amazon S3 Object Lock Overview in the Amazon S3 User Guide.**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html

Comment: In our design the file is given to the presigned url through different service

Comment: @FaisalIqbal Then the service should be providing this MD5 as header in the presigned URL you receive.  If you dont have the file, you cant get its MD5.

Comment: Is there any way we can do this without MD5

Comment: @FaisalIqbal You could try without (Retention Period) and see if it allows you.

Comment: I did but the issue is same

Comment: Replying because this worked for me. We have a service responsible for creating just the presgined URLs. So any other service or UI requesting the file will have the file physically or as a InputStream. So with the request from any of the source to generate presigned URL I asked for md5 in the request body as well and when the uploading the file using the generated presigned URL I pass content-md5 in request header of the presigned URL again. Which actually solves the issue. More over having the permissions is primary thing. Thanks.